# Inserting characters in a string via for loop

Tags: java, string, loops

I want to insert characters in a String with a for loop. I know how to do it without a for loop:

```
String s = "Hello";
String x = " ";
x = s.substring(0, 1) + "*" +s.substring(1, 2) + "*" + s.substring(2,3) +"*"+s.substring(3,4) +"*" +s.substring(4,5);
System.out.println(x);
```

But now when it comes to do it in a loop, I have a problem. My approach is the following:

```
String y ="";
for(int i= 0; i<=s.length(); i++){
    y = s.substring(0, i) + "*" +s.substring(i);
}
System.out.println(y);
```

Comment: Does it have to be loop?

Comment: `String y = s.replaceAll("(?!^|$)", "*");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `charAt` method , in your second code , just be aware of String bounds , not to get `StringIndexOutOfBoundException` :

```
String x = "Hello";
String y =String.valueOf(x.charAt(0));
for(int i= 1; i<x.length(); i++)
   y += "*"+x.charAt(i);
System.out.println(y);
```

my advice is Use `StringBuilder` Instead of String , it's more **Efficient**:

```
String x = "Hello";
StringBuilder y = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(x.charAt(0)));
for(int i= 1; i<x.length(); i++)
   y.append("*").append(x.charAt(i));
System.out.println(y);
```

in this example the output for both codes is `H*e*l*l*o`

Comment: Few problems: (1) your examples will not compile, (2) they will not provide expected results. Also we don't really *must* use `charAt`, there are other ways.

Comment: Only first example does what OP expects. `new StringBuilder(x.charAt(0))` doesn't do what you think it does. Hint: there is no `StringBuilder(char)` constructor, instead `StringBuilder(int)` is used.

Comment: Using a `StringBuilder` is usually more efficient, initializing it via `new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(x.charAt(0)))` is not. Why not `StringBuilder y = new StringBuilder().append(x.charAt(0));`?

Comment: @Holger there is no reason , your solution is better , mine is slower than yours

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
    String input = "TestInput";

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append(input.charAt(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++) {
        b.append("*").append(input.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

gives:

```
T*e*s*t*I*n*p*u*t
```

Is this what you wanted?

**Edit:**
Pshemo's suggestion - use `StringJoiner` (Java 8 solution)

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("*");
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            sj.add(input.substring(i, i + 1));
        }
        System.out.println(sj.toString());
```

And no `StringBuilder` version:

```
  String input="TestInput";
    String y = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        y += "*" + input.charAt(i);
    }
```

And to your knowlage - using string concatenation is discouraged. It is better to use `StringBuilder` or `StringJoiner`

Comment: Or since Java 8 we can use `StringJoiner` with `*` as delimiter.

Comment: yea thats basically what i want. im pretty new to java and i dont know the append method yet. is it possible to do it without .append?

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8+ you can do the following

```
String x = "Hello";
String result = Stream.of(x.split(""))
                      .collect(Collectors.joining("*"));
```

Result `H*e*l*l*o`.

Basically, you are creating a stream of Strings with length 1 and collecting them using a Collector that joins them using `*`. In this approach you don't have to consider any spacial cases like the last/first element or remove extra * from end etc..

Answer (score 3):

```
        String s = "Hello";
        String x = String.join("*",s.split(""));
        System.out.println(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String insertChar(String str, char character){

    char[] charArray=str.toCharArray();
    String result="";
    for(int i=0;i<charArray.length;i++){
        result=result+charArray[i];
        if(i<charArray.length-1){
            result=result+character;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

System.out.println(insertChar("Hello",'*'));

Answer (score 0):

You can follow following code snippet using loop (as you mentioned) to add character to string.

```
    String s = "HelloWorld";
    String y ="";
    Character c = '*';
    int length = s.length();

    for(int i = 1; i<= length; i++) {
        if(i == length)
            y += s.substring(i-1, i);
        else
            y += s.substring(i-1, i) + c;
    }

    System.out.println(y);
```